# Error with importing yfinance dataframe for TA-LIB usage

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib, yfinance

I just learned about using yfinance to import market data for technical analysis. Both yfinance and ta-lib were properly installed already. I used the yf.download method and checked that the data is in dataframe format. This was ran on Jupyter notebook.

```py
import talib
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data = yf.download("MSFT","2015-01-01")
type(data)
data.head()

# Everything up to this point seems fine. I then tried to use the data as the input parameters for ta-lib (ADX as one example).

AvgDaily = talib.ADX('High','Low','Close', timeperiod = 10)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-886a1aac12f8> in <module>
----> 1 real = talib.ADX('High','Low','Close', timeperiod = 10)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\talib\__init__.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     25 
     26             if index is None:
---> 27                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     28 
     29             # Use Series' float64 values if pandas, else use values as passed

TypeError: Argument 'high' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got str)
```

If I simply try to call the values in the dataframe, it seems fine:

`data.High`

Answer (score 0):

There's a new library that was built by Daniel Rodriguez, same fellow who built [backtrader](https://www.backtrader.com/), that makes working with ta-lib a lot easier.

The library is called [btalib](https://btalib.backtrader.com/).

Once installed you simply give it the full OHLCV dataframe, it knows which columns to use, and it will spitout the column you are looking for.

```
import yfinance as yf
import btalib

btalib.ADX(yf.download("msft", start="2019-01-01")).df
```

The return item is an object. Using '.df' gives you the output attributes signal which is a dataframe.

The docstrings are detailed. If there are attributes they can just be added in.

```
print(btalib.ADX(yf.download("msft", start="2019-01-01"), period=21).df[50:])

Date             
2019-03-15 20.281
2019-03-18 21.011
2019-03-19 21.832
2019-03-20 22.661
2019-03-21 23.739
2019-03-22 24.749
2019-03-25 25.457
2019-03-26 26.234
2019-03-27 26.520
2019-03-28 26.792
2019-03-29 27.179
2019-04-01 27.680
2019-04-02 28.218
2019-04-03 28.882
2019-04-04 29.226
2019-04-05 29.553
2019-04-08 29.588
2019-04-09 29.598
2019-04-10 29.773
2019-04-11 30.039
2019-04-12 30.318
2019-04-15 30.704
2019-04-16 30.865
2019-04-17 31.061
2019-04-18 31.582
2019-04-22 32.165
2019-04-23 32.983
```